# Clang-format plugin for visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, clang-format

I'm switching to visual studio 2017. [The clang-format plugin](http://llvm.org/builds/) does not seem to be compatible with this version yet.

Is there a way to force visual studio to use the old plugin anyway ? Is it compatible ?

Is there a not yet released version of the plugin that I can find somewhere or build myself ?

Comment: Just for completeness: It was [now released for VS2107](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HansWennborg.ClangFormat).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I checked the [clang mailing list](http://lists.llvm.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/cfe-dev) and it looks like [Hugo Puhlmann](https://reviews.llvm.org/p/hstefan/)'s already done the changes but hasn't submitted a patch yet:

1. http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2017-January/052243.html
2. http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2017-January/052251.html
3. http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2017-January/052253.html
4. http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2017-January/052484.html

Update: Just sent him a message on Twitter. He responded:

> "I'll have a look at it today and submit an updated build, since there
>   seems to be more interest on it."

Update (again): Hugo's posted a link to his build below.

Comment: Just looked at it. This was back in January and I don't see any follow up to this discussion. Please, keep us informed if you have more info from him on Twitter.

Comment: I just submited the patch to the mail list, hopefully it's going to be merged soon, but if you don't wanna wait I have my own build here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/287376/ClangFormat.vsix.

Comment: Works for me, although it shows a warning during installation.

Comment: Works for me too with the same warning. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can

1. Download the latest Clang-format for visual studio 2013 and then
2. Unpackage the *.vsix file with 7-zip
3. Add one section like the section in the "extension.vsixmanifest" xml file to suuport VS2013 and change the version to "15.0"
4. Then re-package all the files to a zip archive with 7-zip and rename its extension to *.vsix.

Now you have a clang-format extension installation package supports VS2017.